# Using JsonPath when you don't know if you're dealing with an object or array

Tags: json, jsonpath

Given the following JSON:

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

We can use a path expression like `$.store.book[*].author` to get all the authors. But what if we don't know beforehand whether `book` is an array or an object, e.g. what if we could have the above JSON but also something like this:

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
        },
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
         }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

Is there a "generic path" that could be used to get all authors in either case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use:

```
$.store..author
```

Testable here:

https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/

'Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any way I could include `book` in the path? If there is book->author and periodicals->author I'd get both sets of authors back from that path, right? What if I only want to get back `book` authors?

Comment: Sure. Then you may write: $.store.book..author which also works with both JSON shapes, to capture "author"(s) only when descendants from "book"(s)